# Sinon.JS with Angular to mock API calls

Tags: javascript, angular, mocking, sinon

I'm working on an Angular project. I still don't have an actual API but I have the fully completed API contact.

I just want to integrate Sinon.JS with my angular application to mock all the external API calls so that even without the API i should be able to navigate here and there in the application with mock data. But once I have the APIs, I should be able to tell my Angular App not to use the mocks but use the real API.

I just want to know if this sound like a good plan. If yes, it would be great if someone can help me on this with a sample code.